# Excel - type mismatch error 13 in VBA when selecting multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I an new to VBA and I've encountered a small problem. The code works fine when I select only one cell. But when I try to select multiple cells, it says type mismatch. 
I appreciate any help :) and here is the code:

```
Sub Asterisk()
Dim Cell As Range
If Selection.Value = "<.0001" Then
    Selection.Value = 0.0001
Else
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value
        If (Selection.Value < 0.001) Then
            Selection.Value = "***"
        ElseIf (Selection.Value >= 0.001) And (Selection.Value < 0.01) Then
            Selection.Value = "**"
        ElseIf (Selection.Value >= 0.01) And (Selection.Value < 0.05) Then
            Selection.Value = "*"
        Else
            Selection.Value = "Not significant"
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to do a For Each loop to go through each cell in Selection.  That way it will work regardless of whether or not you have a single cell or multiple cells selected.

Comment: Thank you so much! But how would I do that?

Comment: @tigeravatar this should be an Answer, not a Comment

Comment: what is the point of using `Selection.Value = Selection.Value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per tigeravatar's suggestion, here is how you would use a for each to loop through the cells in a selection

```
Sub Asterisk()
Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Value = "<.0001" Then
            Cell.Value = 0.0001
        Else
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value
                If (Cell.Value < 0.001) Then
                    Cell.Value = "***"
                ElseIf (Cell.Value >= 0.001) And (Cell.Value < 0.01) Then
                    Cell.Value = "**"
                ElseIf (Cell.Value >= 0.01) And (Cell.Value < 0.05) Then
                    Cell.Value = "*"
                Else
                    Cell.Value = "Not significant"
                End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: will blow up with a *type mismatch* or something else, depending on what `Selection` is (it could be anything from a `Chart` to a `Range` or a `Shape`).

Comment: do not use `Selection` ... refer to cells directly. for example:  `For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:b7")`